# Uncompress data from Tiled json file with zlib C++

Tags: c++, json, base64, zlib, compression

I have been trying to read, decode and then compress data from a json Tiled file such as the one below:

```
{ "height":40,
 "layers":[
        {
         "compression":"zlib",
         "data":"eJztmNkKwjAQRaN9cAPrAq5Yq3Xf6v9\/nSM2VIbQJjEZR+nDwQZScrwztoORECLySBcIgZ7nc2y4KfyWDLx+Jb9nViNgDEwY+KioAXUgQN4+zpoCMwPmQAtoAx2CLFbA2oDEo9+hwG8DnIDtF\/2K8ks086Tw2zH0uyMv7HcRr\/6\/EvvhnsPrsrxwX7rwU\/0ODig\/eV3mh3N1ld8eraWPaX6+64s9McesfrqcHfg1MpoifxcVEWjukyw+9AtFPl\/I71pER3Of6j4bv7HI54s+MChhqLlPdZ\/P3qMmFuo5h5NnTOhjM5tReN2yT51n5\/v7J3F0vi46fk+ne7aX0i9l6If7mpufTX3f5wsqv9TAD2fJLT9VrTn7UeZnM5tR+v0LMQOHXwFnxe2\/warGFRWf8QDjOLfP",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":40,
         "name":"Ground",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":40,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextobjectid":1,
 "orientation":"orthogonal",
 "properties":
    {

    },
 "renderorder":"right-down",
 "tileheight":32,
 "tilesets":[
        {
         "firstgid":1,
         "source":"..\/..\/..\/Volumes\/Tiled 0.14.2\/examples\/desert.tsx"
        }],
 "tilewidth":32,
 "version":1,
 "width":40
}
```

I'm using the libraries 
 1. "json" (https://github.com/nlohmann/json), 
 2. "base64" (http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html) and 
 3. "zlib" (http://zlib.net).

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "json.hpp"
#include "base64.hpp"
#include "zlib.h"

using json = nlohmann::json;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

// Get string from json file
ifstream t("/Users/Klas/Desktop/testmap_zlib_compressed.json");
stringstream ss;
ss << t.rdbuf();
string sd = ss.str();

// Parse json string
auto j = json::parse(sd);

// Get encoded data
string encoded = j["layers"][0]["data"];

printf("Encoded: \n\n%s\n\n", encoded.c_str());

// Decode encoded data
string decoded = base64_decode(encoded);

// Convert string to char array
char b[decoded.size() + 1];
strcpy(b, decoded.c_str());

// Set size of uncompressed and compressed data
uLong h = j["layers"][0]["height"];
uLong w = j["layers"][0]["width"];
uLong ucompSize = w * h * 4; // Estimate
uLong compSize = strlen(b);

char c[ucompSize];

printf("Decoded (Compressed): \n\n%s\n\n\n", b);

// Uncompress data
uncompress((Bytef *)c, &ucompSize, (Bytef *)b, compSize);

printf("Decoded (Uncompressed): \n\n%s\n\n\n", c);

return 0;
}
```

When I run the program with the json file I get the output:

Encoded:

eJztmNkKwjAQRaN9cAPrAq5Yq3Xf6v9/nSM2VIbQJjEZR+nDwQZScrwztoORECLySBcIgZ7nc2y4KfyWDLx+Jb9nViNgDEwY+KioAXUgQN4+zpoCMwPmQAtoAx2CLFbA2oDEo9+hwG8DnIDtF/2K8ks086Tw2zH0uyMv7HcRr/6/EvvhnsPrsrxwX7rwU/0ODig/eV3mh3N1ld8eraWPaX6+64s9McesfrqcHfg1MpoifxcVEWjukyw+9AtFPl/I71pER3Of6j4bv7HI54s+MChhqLlPdZ/P3qMmFuo5h5NnTOhjM5tReN2yT51n5/v7J3F0vi46fk+ne7aX0i9l6If7mpufTX3f5wsqv9TAD2fJLT9VrTn7UeZnM5tR+v0LMQOHXwFnxe2/warGFRWf8QDjOLfP

Decoded (Compressed):

x\234\355\230\331
\3020E\243}p\353\256X\253u\337\352\377\235#6T\206\320&1G\351\303\301Rr\2743\266\203\221"\362H\201\236\347sl\270)\374\226\274~%\277gV#`L\370\250\250u @\336>Κ3\346@h\202,V\300ڀģߡ\300o\234\200\355\375\212\362K4\363\244\360\3331\364\273#/\354w\257\376\277\373\341\236\303벼p_\272\360S\375(?y]\346\207su\225\337\255\245\217i~\276\353\213=1Ǭ~\272\234\37052\232"h\356\223,>\364E>_\310\357ZDGs\237\352>\277\261\310\347\213>0(a\250\271Ou\237\317ޣ&\3529\207\223gL\350c3\233QxݲO\235g\347\373\373'qt\276.:~O\247{\266\227\322/e\350\207\373\232\233\237M}\337\347*\277\324\300g\311-?U\2559\373Q\346g3\233Q\372\3751\207_g\305\355\277\301\252\306\237\361

Decoded (Uncompressed):

Program ended with exit code: 0

Everything seems to be working fine before it comes to the uncompressing. I'm not sure what goes wrong. Any help to figure this out is appreciated.

Comment: Decompresses fine as a zlib stream. You are not checking the return code of `uncompress()`. What is the return code? The sixth commandment: _If a function be advertised to return an error code in the event of difficulties, thou shalt check for that code, yea, even though the checks triple the size of thy code and produce aches in thy typing fingers, for if thou thinkest ``it cannot happen to me'', the gods shall surely punish thee for thy arrogance._

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strlen()` on binary data. If there is a zero in there, it has nothing to do with the length of the binary data. If there isn't a zero in there, you will run off the end of the data looking for a zero. Use `decoded.size()`.

You can't use `strcpy()` for the same reason. Use `memcpy()`. Or in this case I don't see why you would even copy it.  Just give `decoded.str()` and `decoded.size()` to `uncompress()`.

You can't necessarily print the compressed or uncompressed data as a string (`%s`), again for the *same* reason. In fact, the uncompressed data in this case consists mostly of zeros.